# Uncaught Error when loading page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I( have an MVC 5 application that is also using angularjs and boot strap.  When the page loads the modal doesnt launch and i get the following err in the console:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2….c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A60248%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A431)

Here is my html:

Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app ="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Temujin @ViewBag.Title</title>

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/Login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Temujin", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Temujin</p>
    </footer>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Directive template:

```
<div class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-signin" name="authForm" ng-submit="auth()" ng-controller ="AuthController" novalidate>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="user name" ng-model ="AuthController.user.username" required autofocus>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model ="AuthController.user.password" required>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

cshtml:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Login";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2></h2>
<div id="loginBox">
  <auth-modal></auth-modal>
</div>
```

angularjs:

```
(function () {
    var temujin = angular.module('temujin', []);

    temujin.controller('AuthModalController', ['$scope',function ($scope) {
    $scope.temujin.user = {};
    console.log("AuthModalController ran");
    $scope.$(".modal").modal({ message: 'HEll0 World' });
    }]);

temujin.directive("authModal", function () {
    return { restrict: 'E', templateUrl: '\\js\\templates\\auth-modal.html', controller: 'AuthModalController',controllerAs: 'authmodalCtrl'}
});

temujin.controller('AuthController',['$scope',function ($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    console.log("AuthController ran");
    $scope.auth = function () {
        console.log("user " + this.user);

    };
}]);
})();
```

MVC 5 controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace temujin.Controllers
{
public class TemujinController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Temujin/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to use the module `myApp` in your page here:

```
<html ng-app ="myApp">
```

But your actual module is named `temujin`

You just need to change your `ng-app` directive to point to the right module name.

```
<html ng-app ="temujin">
```